# Python application using office365 exchange server timing out

Tags: python, email

I have a Python program that collects about 11K entries from a CORBA database, then uses those entries to parse through about 1,0000 Mb of text files.  This entire process normally takes 5-7 minutes.  I log into the Exchange365 server before this starts (so that any unusual events can be emailed to the administrator) and then try to email the results to the 'normal' recipients.  That last email is failing and the root cause seems to be that I am getting logged off of the Exchange server.

Adding a 'dummy' email about half way through the processing seems to eliminate the timeout, but I'd like to find a more programatic way to accomplish this.  Following is a code snippet where I enable the email:

```
import smtp
import time

pretty_localtime = time.asctime()
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
#
try:
    smtpserver.login(office365_user,office365_pwd)
except:
    msg = ("%s --- FATAL ERROR:  Couldn't log into SMTP server.")%pretty_localtime
    log_file.write("%s \n"%msg)
    print msg
    sys.exit()
```

Has anyone worked through this problem?

*****edit**** Python error added:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "piu_billing.py", line 739, in <module>
    log_file.write(email_msg)
  File "piu_billing.py", line 102, in send_mail
    smtpserver.sendmail(office365_user,to,themsg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 719, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.mail(from_addr, esmtp_opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 471, in mail
    self.putcmd("mail", "FROM:%s%s" % (quoteaddr(sender), optionlist))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 334, in putcmd
     self.send(str)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 324, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('Server not connected')
    smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Server not connected
```

Comment: Since you catch all exceptions you don't know if this was a login error or any number of problems. You should at least print the actual exception and then narrow your except clause to smtp errors (it can be difficult to guess all the errors, but dir(smtplib) gives you a start).

Comment: Agreed, I could catch the exception and re-initate the login, but I'd like to find way to avoid the timeout.  5-7 minutes seems overly restrictive to me.